# UniSharp/laravel-filemanager error (Trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.4

I'm using UniSharp/laravel-filemanager with tinyMCE 4. When I click file explorer button. I gives out error in a bootstrap model. And the error is

```
Trying to get property of non-object
(View: F:\moonlight\resources\views\public\tour\single.blade.php)
```

It is requesting for route`(single.tour) which looks like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('{category}/{slug}','GetPublicController@singleTour')
            ->where('category', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+')
            ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+')
            ->name('single.tour');
});
```

when I comment out the above route file explorer works perfectly.